# Changing properties of Datepicker on Dropdown list change not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I have a `dropdown list` and a `input textbox` that is bound with a `datepicker` class

on document.ready, I have initialized the datepicker with this properties:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#<%=txtCheckDate.ClientID%>").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
  });
});
```

Now when a specific value is selected in dropdown list, I need to disable the future dates. It works when I try to disable it in the document.ready in the first place but on runtime, it won't update. I tried the destroy/refresh functions but nothing happens.

```
$("#<%=ddlPaymentType.ClientID%>").on('change', function () {
  var selected = $(this).val();
  $("#<%=txtCheckDate.ClientID%>").datepicker('destroy');
  if (selected == "3" || selected == "4") {
    $("#<%=txtCheckDate.ClientID%>").datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
      endDate: 'now'
    });
  } else {
    $("#<%=txtCheckDate.ClientID%>").datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
    });
  }
  $("#<%=txtCheckDate.ClientID%>").datepicker('refresh');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#<%=txtCheckDate.ClientID%>").datepicker("option", {
      autoclose: true,
      format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
    });
```

Comment: the new version should have future dates disabled so this should have a property " endDate: 'now' "

Comment: I just want you to try this syntax :)

Comment: No, it did not do anything